# Trouble saving complex plots in Octave

Tags: plot, octave

I'm running Octave 3.6.4 on a Windows 7 system.

I'm having a hard time saving plots as .png files. Plots that are somewhat complex (several subplots, lots of legends, 1.6 million datapoints) can only be saved using an very large image size, and even that works only sometimes.

A specific example (with titles and axis labels left out):

```
figure (11)
clf ;

subplot (1,2,1) ;
plot (ratingRepeated, (predictions - Ymean)(:), ".k", "markersize", 1) ;
axis([0.5 5.5 -4 8]) ;
grid("on") ;

subplot (1,2,2) ;
plot (ratingRepeated, predictions(:), ".k", "markersize", 1) ;
axis([0.5 5.5 -4 8]) ;
grid("on") ;
```

Generates a nice plot with millions of datapoints. But using:

```
print -dpng figure11
```

creates an image containing only a small portion of the plot. Sometimes it helps using a very large image like this:

```
print -dpng "-S3400,2400" figure11
```

But mostly Octave just stalls, then crashes after CTRL+C.

I have without success tried:

- Using Octave 3.8.x
- Using gnuplot rather than "fltk": graphics_toolkit ("gnuplot")
- Closing all but one plot before saving
- Maximizing the plot window
- Searched high and low for a solution

Some minor but possible related issues are: Danish characters won't show up; extremely slow performance with plots taking several minutes to display and/or save.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would argue that you are trying to fix the problem in the wrong way. You have too many data points and a normal scatter plot, like what you are trying to do, will not give you a good display of the distribution of data. Instead, use some sort of density plot. Just compare this two:

```
x = vertcat (randn (2000000, 1)*3, randn (1000000, 1) +5);
y = vertcat (randn (2000000, 1)*3, randn (1000000, 1) +5);
plot (x, y, ".")
```

[image: simply plotting the thousand of data points]

```
pkg load statistics;
data = hist3 ([x y], [100 100]);
imagesc (data)
axis xy
colormap (hot (124)(end:-1:1,:)) # invert colormap since hot ends in white
```

[image: imagesc with inverted hot colormap]

You can use one the the existing colormaps (see `colormap list`) or create your own.  The most common is jet (not for being good but because it's the default)

```
colormap (jet (124))
```

[image: imagesc with jet colormap]

Comment: Thank you so much, @carandraug, that's a very useful idea. I should point out, however, that detailed but not-so-dense plots also tend to cause trouble. [Like this one](http://www.lassehjorthmadsen.dk/figure3.png)

Comment: @LasseHjorthMadsen plotting all those points is heavy work because, well, there's a lot of points, even if most of them will overlap. I spent a lot of time trying to do it before, until I figured out that I was looking at the problem the wrong away.

Comment: Thanks again, @carandraug. To be clear: I get the same problem with a plot of just some 1700 datapoints